# How to split on the special character "["} in Rstudio

Tags: r, text, split, stringr

I am relatively new to R, and I am stuck with splitting a string. I hope someone can help me out or point me  in the right directory.

What I try to do is split the following string:

```
"[ac BK]"
```

I just want to have two columns:

1: ac, 2: BK

I tried the separate and the stringr functions but it didn't work. One of the things I tried:

```
(str_split(handhistory$poker,"\\["))
```

Hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The split pattern has to be something that divides the substrings you want.
You are trying to [split](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_split) by the '[' if you do that on "[ac BK]" the result will be ['', 'ac BK]']. The character that divides the two substrings you want is ' ' so you can split using this char.
Also use [replace](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_replace) to clear the string from unwanted chars ('[', ']')

```
library('stringr')
str = "[ac BK]"
str_split(str_replace_all(str, "[\\[\\]]", ""), " ")
```